# Is there possible get the prompts list from BO file via using NET BO SDK?

Tags: business-objects-sdk

Is there possible get the prompts list from BO file via using BO NET SDK?

for example, I launch a application, then load a rep file, after that, the application tell me, in this rep file, there are 3 prompts

1. First one is:???? type is:???
2. 2nd one is:??? type is:???
3. 3rd one is:??? type is ???

   ```
   busobj.Application boApp = new busobj.Application();
   boApp.Logon(GlobalClass.user.strUsrId, GlobalClass.user.strPWD, "@bopfast", "LDAP", false, false);
   boApp.Interactive = false;
   boApp.Visible = false;
   busobj.Document testDoc = new busobj.Document();
   testDoc = (busobj.Document)boApp.Documents.Open("C:\\test.rep", true, false, null, null);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible to do this in Java :

```
    /* Connect to CMS */
    ISessionMgr sessionMgr = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
    enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.logon(user, pass, host, auth);

    /* Initialize Webi report engine */
    reportEngines = (ReportEngines) enterpriseSession.getService("ReportEngines");
    ReportEngine reportEngine = (ReportEngine) reportEngines.getService(ReportEngines.ReportEngineType.WI_REPORT_ENGINE);

    /* Open report */
    DocumentInstance doc = reportEngine.openDocument(rapport_id);
    doc.refresh();

    /* Get Prompts */
    Prompts prompts = doc.getPrompts();
    System.out.println("Total Prompts : " + prompts.getCount())

    Prompts prompts = doc.getPrompts();
    for (int s = 0; s < prompts.getCount(); s++) {
        Prompt prompt = prompts.getItem(s);
        System.out.println("Prompt name : " + prompt.getID());
    }
```

You can find some samples here for .NET SDK : http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports+for+.NET+SDK+Samples

And here you have Sample Applications for Business Intelligence Software Developer Kits :
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-51445

Hope it helps.